# Visual Editor for Apache Camel

Tags: ide, apache-camel, visual-editor

I am new to Apache Camel and wonder if there is any open source visual editor for it similar to JBoss Fuse. Please share what you guys use for visual editing or simple visualizing of Apache Camel. Many thanks!

Comment: Honestly, you are better off using the java dsl for coding and then use hawtio for visualizing your flows and accessing other stuff.

Comment: Thanks! Can you pls share a link/resource to set hawtio with java app running in eclipse?

Comment: Look at the hawtio website. There are good instructions there.

Answer (score 7):

There is Fuse Tools for Apache Camel that has a visual editor with drag-drop capabilities

- https://tools.jboss.org/features/fusetools.html

That is a set of Eclipse plugins you can install. It's free to use and supports XML editing of standard Apache Camel XML files.

Answer (score 2):

There is Karavan (Apache Camel Karavan) an VSCode extension, that can also be used as a standalone webapp, visual editor for creating [YAML](https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/next/languages/yaml.html) files.

- https://github.com/apache/camel-karavan

If you have docker, you can run it with:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v $(pwd):/deployments/integrations ghcr.io/apache/camel-karavan-native:latest
```

> This will run Karavan webapp at HTTP port 8080 on localhost, note you will need a directory `deployments/integrations` on your current directory before run this comand (you can also change it to what you want), this directory is where your integration files will be persisted.

Answer (score 2):

There are several projects that offer visual / low-code tools for Apache Camel:

- [Fuse Tools](https://tools.jboss.org/features/fusetools.html) (Eclipse IDE)
- [Karavan](https://github.com/apache/camel-karavan) (Visual Studio Code / Standalone)
- [Camel Designer](https://github.com/designer-for-camel/camel-designer) (Visual Studio Code)
- [Hawtio](https://github.com/hawtio) (Web Monitoring)
- [Syndesis](https://github.com/syndesisio) (Web)
- [Assimbly](https://github.com/assimbly/gateway) (Web)
- [Kaoto](https://github.com/KaotoIO) (Web)

The first three are EDI plugins, the others are self-hosted web applications/platforms.

Note: There is also a graphical mapper:

- [Atlas Map](https://www.atlasmap.io/) / [Camel Documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/atlasmap-component.html)